# ¿Debería guardar HTML en la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Quiero guardar las etiquetas span que contienen los mensajes de un chat, para posteriormente obtener el texto y meterlos en la caja del chat... pero según he escuchado no está bien hacerlo, alojar *HTML* en la base de datos, entonces ¿Cómo debería guardar un mensaje en la base de datos sin tener que crear cada fila para un mensaje?

```html
<!-- QUIERO GUARDAR UN MENSAJE -->
<span data-fecha="8/09/2021" data-by="4585477458">Hola</span>
<span data-fecha="8/09/2021" data-by="4585477778">Hola!</span>
<!-- ETC... -->
```

Comment: Toda esa informacion son diferentes columnas.. y cada mensaje es una fila.. no entiendo que queres guardar en la db...

Comment: @gbianchi No sería gastar mucho espacio en la base de datos crear un registro para un solo mensaje?

Comment: Si no creas un registro por cada mensaje... Cómo distingues los mensajes y si por ejemplo, a futuro quieren eliminar una línea... 
Y como te comenta el compañero gbianchi, fecha, by y el texto, son 3 columnas distintas, no son 1 columna.... Para lo único que tendría sentido almacenar HTML en la base de datos, sería por guardar el formato, aún así... Hay que procesarlo antes, pero no recuerdo de qué forma.
Las bbdd están para guardar información. Organiza bien las PKs y los índices, y todo debería ir rápido.

Comment: El verdadero problema no es guardarlo. Es como lo vas a usar luego. Renderizas ese html directamente? Ese HTML viene de un input de usuario? Sería muy sencillo con ese planteamiento colarte un ataque de tipo XSS.

Comment: @RubénEspada porque digamos en el registro va la id de usuario, ciudad, mensajes, en mensajes meto todo el contenido, osea los span...

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo No, el usuario puede escribir codigo pero se convierte en texto plano... lo que se hace es que se coge el texto y se mete en una etiqueta span internamente

Comment: Y si.. si es un chat, son muchos registros.. salvo que vayas borrando historia... ademas.. porque pensas que muchos registros es mas informacion que un HTML completo que tiene un monton de informacion que es siempre igual y que tranquilamante tiene que estar fuera????

Comment: No es cierto que no se deba guardar HTML en una base de datos o que esto sea peligroso... todo depende del uso y de si usas o no código seguro para guardar/leer/mostrar esa información. La cuestión aquí es si conviene o no **para este caso** guadar HTML. Yo diría que no. Guardar esto en HTML ocuparía más espacio y sería más lento (imagina que en un determinado contexto quisieras recuperar todos los mensajes de un determinado usuario, o borrarlos, etc). O, imagina que tu contexto evoluciona y ahora quieres mostrar la información también en una aplicación móvil...

Comment: ... Son sólo algunos ejemplos de contextos que podrían ayudarte a decidir lo que sea mejor a la hora de escribir un programa y diseñar datos. Por eso, para el caso que expones lo mejor es diseñar una base de datos donde guardes los campos como fecha, usuario, mesaje ... y todo lo demás lo trabajes en el contexto. Así, consutas a la base de datos, obtienes los datos puros y formateas en el contexto, añadiendo los span y demás al momento de presentar la información. Esto te permitiría adaptar tu aplicación fácilmente a cualquier evolución futura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es buena práctica guardar html en la base de datos puede haber filtrado xss y ademas no necesitas por que para eso puedes utilizar un foreach en javascript para recorer todos los datos traídos de la base de datos

1. Ej 1)

puedes crear tres cols en mysql y ahí guardar fecha usuario y mensaje,
**tbl_mensajes**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Ej 2)

crear un campo json y ahí guardar el mensaje sin tener que guardar tags html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[
    {
        "mej":"Hola",
        "data_by": 4585477458,
        "date": "8/09/2021"
    },
    {
        "mej":"Hola!",
        "data_by": 4585477778,
        "date": "8/09/2021"
    }
]
```

la diferencia sería que cada mensaje se iria en una sola col de mysql